# IzPack executable not working for linux scripts

Tags: java, izpack

I am trying to create the installer for my one of java applications.

As per documentation [here](http://izpack.org/documentation/installation-files.html#executable-mark-file-executable-or-execute-it), executable is used to execute sumthing during installation process or it can be used to set executable flag in unix-like systems.

But when I am using the same inside one of my packs it does not do anything. So my Job is getting failed with below exception.

> Java.io.IOException: Cannot run program /home/user/1.0/installations/test.sh: error=13, Permission Denied

Below is the pack definition inside the install.xml

```
<pack name="Install Database Server" required="no" preselected="no"
installGroups="New Application">
    <description>New server installation of the selected database as
        required by the application.
    </description>
    <fileset dir="installations" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/$APP_VERSION/installations">
        <include name="**" />
    </fileset>
    <executable target="$INSTALL_PATH/$APP_VERSION/installations/test.sh"
        stage="never" keep="true" os="unix">
    </executable>
</pack>
```

And below is the Job inside process specification xml file.

```
<job name="TestInstaller">
    <executefile name="$INSTALL_PATH/$APP_VERSION/installations/test.sh">
    </executefile>
</job>
```

So can anyone please help me out in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`os` is a nested **element** not an attribute. Please change your install.xml as follows:

```
<executable target="$INSTALL_PATH/$APP_VERSION/installations/test.sh"
    stage="never" keep="true">
    <os family="unix" />
</executable>
```

To prevent that your executable also gets called under non-unix operating systems you should also add that element to your process specification XML:

```
<job name="TestInstaller">
    <executefile name="$INSTALL_PATH/$APP_VERSION/installations/test.sh">
        <os family="unix" />
    </executefile>
</job>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using ProcessPanel then you can set it directly like this:

```
<pack name="Pack" id="pack" required="yes">
  <description>Pack</description>
  <executable targetfile="${INSTALL_PATH}/bin/run.sh" os="unix" stage="never" failure="warn" keep="true" />
</pack>
```